# Symfony 2 - Clone entity to different table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am trying to clone an entity-object to a different table in Symfony 2 / Doctrine. Any idea how to do this?

After retrieving the object from the database I can clone it like this:

```
$newobject = clone $oldbject;
```

This gives me a new object, which I can persist as a new record to the same table in the database. Actually I dont want to do this. I want to store the object as it is to a different table in the database. But to do this, I would have to change the parent entity, right? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

But then you're not really *cloning* an entity. In fact, you want a different entity. What do the two entities look like? Do they have the same fields? You could do something like this:

```
$oldEntity = $oldEntity;
$newEntity = new NewEntity();
$oldReflection = new \ReflectionObject($oldEntity);
$newReflection = new \ReflectionObject($newEntity);

foreach ($oldReflection->getProperties() as $property) {
    if ($newReflection->hasProperty($property->getName())) {
        $newProperty = $newReflection->getProperty($property->getName());
        $newProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $newProperty->setValue($newEntity, $property->getValue($oldEntity));
    }
}
```

This is untested - and may have an error or two, but this should allow all properties to be copied from one object to another (assuming the properties have the same name on both objects).

Comment: works great! I needed to make the old properties accessible too, but thats the same as for the new one.