# Copy same value From Entity to Entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have Two entity

Comments and BannedComments

the entity have the same field, and when one comment is banned, delete object from Comments Entity and Copy in BannedComments

For Now i use this script
[Symfony 2 - Clone entity to different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216285/symfony-2-clone-entity-to-different-table)

```
$oldEntity = $oldEntity;
$newEntity = new NewEntity();

$oldReflection = new \ReflectionObject($oldEntity);
$newReflection = new \ReflectionObject($newEntity);

foreach ($oldReflection->getProperties() as $property) {
    if ($newReflection->hasProperty($property->getName())) {
        $newProperty = $newReflection->getProperty($property->getName());
        $newProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $newProperty->setValue($newEntity, $property->getValue($oldEntity));
    }
}
```

but i have to change all variable to public...

There is a better way to copy the contents ?

I try to use clone

```
$BannedComments = new BannedComments();
$BannedComments = clone $Comments;
$em->persist($BannedComments);
```

But save in Comments non in BannedComments because when i do Clone Comments, BannedComments is enitity of Comments

Comment: Why didn't you use a `Comment` entity with a boolean for setting a comment as *banned*?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, it's a very specific use case. Does the Comment entity has many attributes? If not, you could write an ad hoc function that receives a Comment object and returns a BannedComment object.

Use getters and setters to avoid having to make them public.

If you insist in the generic approach, use method calls instead of property access, but
sometimes the generic approach is a bit overkill and a waste of time for concrete, non repetitive use cases.