# Replicate entity values with relationship values into another entity

Tags: php, symfony, oop, orm, doctrine-orm

I have entity called user and I want to have exact copy of entity values into another entity called "**history**" or "**cache**" or as "**order** user" for record keeping, so incase user entity values changes, we will have copy of the user values and long list of fields with its sub entities in history.

**Solution**

I have tried this solution, but all my properties are private which is not working for this. because it requires public properties only (unless I'm wrong on this).

[Symfony 2 - Clone entity to different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216285/symfony-2-clone-entity-to-different-table)

Comment: I'd suggest looking into already made functionality https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md | https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

Comment: You could also use reflection to access the private values or setter functions

Comment: @JasonRoman I get this error when using properties "Cannot access non-public member AppBundle\Entity\Coupon::code"

Comment: If you're trying to keep some kind of an audit log, you could also add lifecycle events that log old and new values.

Comment: @Gerben I'm create clone of object into another table after order is been placed, so when looking up, we will lookup on new order table and not the orignal table

Comment: So, when a user places an order, a snapshot of that user entity should be made, so that you can see the user's values at the time the order was placed. Correct? I think I would create a user_version table (one user has many versions), and add a function to the user repository that creates a user snapshot (user_version instance) and returns a reference that you can link to the order. The function could be made smart so that it does not create a new version when it matches the last version.

Comment: @JasonRoman, JimL and Gerben, Thank you for your inputs. I have learned few new things today.

I have found the problem, reflection cannot access private method from previous extended class, but can access self private. so changing to protected  from private on entity solved the issue.  Gerben, I do like your version instance history. maybe useful on some other project.

Comment: If you are interesting in tracking changes it would be much more efficient to only store the change set and not clone the whole object. You can use [the `preUpdate` event](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) and get an array of changed values using `getEntityChangeSet`. It will be easy to implement a history service using this functionality in a doctrine event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by making parent extended entity properties to be protected and following solution worked fine then.

[Symfony 2 - Clone entity to different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216285/symfony-2-clone-entity-to-different-table)

Entity copy

```
class OrderProduct extends Product {
}

// make sure product entity property values are protected and not private.
```

**Solution 2**

Solution by @JmilL and by @Gerben is also something to look into, if you want to keep complete history of all the changes.

> https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit
>
> https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md