# Copy entity to "different class"?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `customer` and an `order` entity. ( doctrine entities )

Both have an `address` associated entity, implementing the same `AddressInterface`

When the customer makes an order, I want to copy the address from the customer to the address of the order. ( I need a copy, as I don't want the order address to change when the customer address changes )

So of course I could do:

```
$orderAddress = new OrderInvoiceAddress();
$orderAddress->setLastName( $customerAddress->getLastName() );
...
...
```

But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way ?

Comment: Take a look at this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216285/symfony-2-clone-entity-to-different-table

Comment: Thanks. I knew about that but I was hoping for something even more elegant ;)

Comment: How about typecasting? `$orderAddress = (OrderInvoiceAddress) $customerAddress;`

Comment: Wow, I did not know one could do that !!

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: After reading a little about this, I doesn't look like this was possible in PHP ( still gonna try it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method:

```
class OrderAddress {

    static function CreateFromCustomerAddress(CustomerAddress $customerAddress)
    {
        $orderAddress=new self();
        $orderAddress->setFirstName($customerAddress->getFirstName());

        return $orderAddress;
    }

    private $firstName;
```

Usage:

```
$orderAddress=OrderAddress::CreateFromCustomerAddress($customerAddress);
```

Comment: Thank you ... but that is exactly the same.

Comment: It is not. 1) You can test the function that converts from one to another. 2) It makes the code way more readable.

Comment: You can use the symfony property accesor. It is quite handy to move data from one place to another as you do but it make it harder to test